# Equal margin between "Dynamic" flex child elements

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

I want **equal margin** between that `three div` even if they are two or even one but there should be **no margin** in the both side child and if it's only one child there should be **no margin**.

Now my code is folowing like this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  background: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  flex: 1;
}

.child:nth-child(2),
.child:last-child {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

.child:first-child {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Am getting the result what I want using the above code.** But I was wondering if there is a better way of attaining this result.

What I want is that margin should be equal in the centre but no margin should be there on the sides of the wrap

*I am not looking for giving padding to the parent*.

Comment: Your "Tip" is not really correct. I'm using flexbox, and even Grid Layout, fine on my iPad without prefixes. Check here for browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @Michael_B My source of the **Tip** is from - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp. So am not sure that `w3schools` can be wrong!!

Comment: Obviously they are wrong because flexbox is working on Safari *without* prefixes on all my iOS devices.

Comment: Yep, you are right I checked in my colleges MacBook. ty for the info I have updated my `Q` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More modern approach, preferred: You can use [`gap`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#gaps) property. Demo:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: #000;
  gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Original answer. You can add `margin-left` only for adjacent `child` blocks using next sibling selector. Demo:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: #000;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.child + .child {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

.child:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.child:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.child:only-child {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `justify-content:space-between` for the checkbox

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  background: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  flex: 1;
}

.child:nth-child(2),
.child:last-child {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

.child:first-child {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```